# Improve Tesseract Accuracy

Tags: python, opencv, tesseract

I have this image and tesseract doesn't seem to convert the text properly, the original image was much bigger and has a lot more noise, I have preprocessed the image to get only the part I want to convert to text. How can I improve the accuracy from here?

[image]

Result from tesseract:

```
Nur Ellyza Eka Putri

6560877
```

I have tried several image and it fail to convert the letter c everytime

Answer (score 0):

to improve tesseract accuracy, have a look at `psm` parameter.
For example, for character recognition, set `psm = 10`.

```
PSM Options:
  0    Orientation and script detection (OSD) only.
  1    Automatic page segmentation with OSD.
  2    Automatic page segmentation, but no OSD, or OCR.
  3    Fully automatic page segmentation, but no OSD. (Default)
  4    Assume a single column of text of variable sizes.
  5    Assume a single uniform block of vertically aligned text.
  6    Assume a single uniform block of text.
  7    Treat the image as a single text line.
  8    Treat the image as a single word.
  9    Treat the image as a single word in a circle.
 10    Treat the image as a single character.
 11    Sparse text. Find as much text as possible in no particular order.
 12    Sparse text with OSD.
 13    Raw line. Treat the image as a single text line,
                        bypassing hacks that are Tesseract-specific.
```

To improve a image with number only , you can set `tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789`.

`PSM` and `tessedit_char_whitelist` are passed into `config=' '` argoument in this way:

```
pytesseract.image_to_string(my_image, ......config=' set-your-parameters-here ' )
```